# How to add reverse number in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to add the reverse number in the array. I wanna add the number in reverse in the array.

```
var totalBidders = 22;
var NoOfWinners = 3;

var arr = [];
let e = totalBidders-NoOfWinners;
for (let i = totalBidders; i > e; i--) {
  console.log( "=>" , i);
  arr.push(i); 
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

But I got this **:**

```
index.js:484 => 22
index.js:486 undefined
index.js:484 => 21
index.js:486 undefined
index.js:484 => 20
index.js:486 undefined
```

Comment: `.push` adds to the end of the array. Consider using `arr[i] = i` instead?

Comment: "add the reverse number in the array" is not a clear definition, please explain further and ideally provide at least one example!

Comment: Try replacing: `console.log(arr[i]);` with: `console.log(arr[arr.length-1]);` assuming you want to print the last item that was pushed into the array

Comment: @Nir Alfasi
sorry if I can't explain exactly.

Comment: The suggestion in the first comment is horrible if you need to do anything else with that array later on. If you don't understand why try to print the array after the loop: `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));`

Comment: @Nir Alfasi
 yes right that's what I want

Comment: @I'MLEEBAN I think that you can try a bit harder to explain what you want to achieve, further "reverse number" doesn't make any sense!

Comment: @NirAlfasi horrible? Ouch. It solves what the OP wants. However it doesn't make it a good idea

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes horrible considering the result array: `[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,20,21,22]`

Comment: @NirAlfasi haha, definitely not a good idea.

Comment: @Nir Alfasi
I think you are right that's my bad

Comment: You would simply `arr.push(totalBidders - (NoOfWinners - (i + 1)));` in a forward loop eg `const arr = Array.from({ length: NoOfWinners }, (_, i) => totalBidders - (NoOfWinners - (i + 1)));`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Array.reverse`

```js
var totalBidders = 22;
var NoOfWinners = 3;

var arr = [];
let e = totalBidders - NoOfWinners;
for (let i = totalBidders; i > e; i--) {
  arr.push(i);
}
arr.reverse();
console.log(arr);
```

**OR**

Simply control the loop variables.

**Sample Implementation**

```js
var totalBidders = 22;
var NoOfWinners = 3;

var arr = [];
let e = totalBidders - NoOfWinners;
for (let i = 1; i <= NoOfWinners; i++) {
  arr.push(e + i);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This is better than my comment suggestion

Comment: Why not just start at `e` and skip the reverse? `for (let i = e; i < totalBidders; i++) { arr.push(i + 1);}`

Comment: @pilchard that's also a great idea thanks.

Comment: @pilchard Lot of other ways. I have added one sample in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way, one-liner if you don't mind:

```js
const totalBidders = 22;
const NoOfWinners = 3;

const arr = [...Array(NoOfWinners).keys()].map((e) => totalBidders - e);

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

> console.log(arr[i])

Will try to access the index `22`, `21` & `20` values from an array `arr` but these indexes does not exist as `arr.push(i)` is pushing the `22`, `21` & `20` as values at `0`, `1` & `2nd` index into an array.

If you want to access the values, You can try this **:**

```
console.log(arr[arr.length-1])
```

**Demo :**

```js
const totalBidders = 22;
const NoOfWinners = 3;

const arr = [];
const e = totalBidders-NoOfWinners;
for (let i = totalBidders; i > e; i--) {
  console.log( "=>" , i);
  arr.push(i); 
  console.log(arr[arr.length - 1]);
}

arr.reverse();
```